# How to Loop through a list of elements

Tags: dart

My question is very simple, how can i create a loop that will loop a simple list of elements.

```
List li=["-","\\","|","/"];
```

this is my dart list and i want to create this simple animation.

Comment: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html

Comment: For what purpose do you want to loop the list?

Comment: This was just to create like an animation of loading.

Comment: Can you please be more specific. Please add some code to your question that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this code to loop through a list:

```
List li=["-","\\","|","/"];
for (var i=0; i<li.length; i++) {
    print(li[i]);
}
```

As to the animation:

HTML

```
    <p id="test">
    test
    </p>
```

Dart

```
  import 'dart:html';
  import 'dart:async';

  main() async {
  List li = ["-", "\\", "|", "/"];
    for (var i = 0; i < 400000000; i++) {
      querySelector('#test').text = li[i % 4];
      (await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 68):

Different ways to Loop through a List of elements

**1 classic For**

```
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  // TO DO
  var currentElement = li[i];
}
```

**2 Enhanced For loop**

```
for(final e in li){
  //
  var currentElement = e;
}
```

Notice the keyword `final`. It means single-assignment, a `final` variable's value cannot be changed.

**3 while loop**

```
var i = 0;
while(i < li.length){
  var currentElement = li[i];
  i++;
}
```

For the `while` loop, you will use `var` to reassign the variable value.

Comment: May I ask what's the difference between 'var' and 'final'?

Comment: abdhoms I guess you don't want to change the value of 'e' inside the for. Once it created with a value it sticks with it until it is destroyed, which happens at the end of each iteration.

Comment: @abdhoms , the difference is that with `var` the variable can be reassigned. `final` means single-assignment, a `final` variable's value cannot be changed.

Answer (score 6):

Another ways of looping through a List in Dart:

**Using the forEach method:**

```
  li.forEach((value) {
    var currentElement = value;
  });
```

**Using a While Loop and an Iterator:**

```
// First, get an iterator to the list:
var myListIter = li.iterator;
 
// Iterate over the list:
while(myListIter.moveNext()){
    var currentElement = myListIter.current;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

there are may methods to get a loop from list
for example we have this type of list

```
var mylist = [6, 7 ,9 ,8];
```

using for each method

```
 mylist.forEach((e){
   print(e);
 });
```

using for Loop

```
for (int i=0 ; i<mylist.length; i++){
   var e = mylist[i];
  print(e);
}
```

Enhanced For loop

```
for (var e in mylist){
   print(e);
}
```

using while loop

```
 var i = 0;
  while(i < mylist.length){
    print(mylist[i]);
   i++;
 }
```