# How to iterate the list from sqflite in the form of integer in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, int, sqflite

I want to add all the numbers from the below list and store it in the variable in dart.

```
_totalExp() async {
  List items = await db.getTotalDailyExp();`enter code here`
  print(items); 
}
```

output: `[{dailyExpenditure: 25}, {dailyExpenditure: 50}, {dailyExpenditure: 25}, ]`

Expected output: 100

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Loop through a list of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514807/how-to-loop-through-a-list-of-elements)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Iterable/reduce.html).

```dart
List items = ...;
int sum = items.reduce((m1, m2) => m1['dailyExpenditure'] + m2['dailyExpenditure']);
```