# how can i access element of list in dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have list of constructors .eg,

```
final data = [
      new sale(price: 5, numOfSales: 1),
      new sale(price: 10, numOfSales: 2),]
```

how can loop on the list and access numOfSales to do some operation on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Loop through a list of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514807/how-to-loop-through-a-list-of-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to calculate total numOfSales from data array you can do it like this
You can use fold  `data.fold(0, (t, e) =>( t as int) + e.numOfSales)`

```
 void main() {

  final data = [
      new sale(price: 5, numOfSales: 1),
      new sale(price: 10, numOfSales: 2),
  ];
  
 final totalNumOfSales= data.fold(0, (t, e) =>( t as int) + e.numOfSales);
  print(totalNumOfSales);
    
}

class sale{
  final int price;
  final int numOfSales;
  
  sale({this.price=0, this.numOfSales=0});
  
  @override
  toString()=>'price: $price, numOfSales: $numOfSales';
  
}
```

Comment: double fun (){

    final totals= seriesList[0].data.fold(0, (t, e) =>( t as double) + e.numOSales);

    return totals;
  } this give me that error "type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double' in type cast"

Comment: can you clerify the question you're trying to ask, do you want to access just one element of the array, e.g data[0].numOfSales or do you want to calculate the total numOfSales for all elements of the array?

Comment: actually i need both. you already tell me the total, now i need just one elment

Comment: i have list of three element [data1 , data2 , data3]. data1 is also a list ```final data1 = [
      new sale(price: 5, numOfSales: 1),
      new sale(price: 10, numOfSales: 2),].``` you told me ho to calculate total of numOfSales in one list which is data1 now  i want to sum just one element of numOfSales of three lists data1 , data2 , data3 just the first element of them