# Fetch data Firestore Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the data where I marked. But since I made the side collection a custom name (as you can see in the picture `TbarRow` and `latpuldown`), I cannot fetch the last data I want to reach. Actually, when I write the name of the collection by hand, I reach it, but I don't know how to fetch that name without writing it myself.

[image: Firestore image (want to fetch thoese data)]

I created an array with the name of `gunharaketisimleri` of the documentation (4 documents `Karın` `bacak` `itiş` `çekiş`) and tried to fetch the data from there.

[image: Firestore image 2]

and try it like this:

```
Future<void> fetchData() async {
  try {
    var snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("günler")
        .doc(currentUserID + " GUN")
        .collection("gün")
        .doc("itiş")
        .get();
    snapshot.data()!.forEach((key, value) {
      List<dynamic> favorites1 = [];
      favorites1.add(value);
      print(favorites1);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle any errors
    print(e.toString());
  }
}
```

and output:

> I/flutter (24013): [[TbarRow, latpuldown]]

> I/flutter (24013): [itiş]

> I/flutter (24013): [null]

> I/flutter (24013):[gdc0mIEbwmdVFqZoLDC0gnIFCAy2]

I tried to reach it this way and got stuck here. Can you suggest another method or how should the continuation be from the final version?

Comment: So you need to read the `itiş` document without knowing the names of `günler` and `gün` collections?

Comment: Actually I know those `günler` `gün` and `itiş`. So i can reach them as i want. @AlexMamo

Comment: Then what's the problem?

Comment: Problem is i can not read `TbarRow` `latpuldown` etc. Look second picture pls. @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the array from the document, would be something like:

```
var array = snapshot.get('gunharaketisimleri') as List;
```

Then you can [loop over the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514807/how-to-loop-through-a-list-of-elements) to get the individual values.